# How to prevent multiple logins for administrator?

Tags: 7, sessions

I have my Drupal website whose admin account is shared. But I want to limit the multiple logins, that is, only one should be able to login at a time. I have already used [Session Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_limit) Module. This works for non-administrator accounts, but not for admin account.

How can I prevent multiple administrators logins?

Comment: They really shouldn't be using a single account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session Limit allows to put restriction on session based on user role, it could be admin role also, with an exception that it does not restrict user with uid 1 which is kind of rescue point in case you misconfigure the module.

I would say instead of finding any module or building any custom solution which can put restriction on uid 1, you use different account with admin role which this/any module can handle gracefully.

**As a thumb rule I don't put any restriction on uid 1.**

If you see the code of session_limit.module line 248

```
function session_limit_init() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid > 1 && !isset($_SESSION['session_limit'])) {

    if (_session_limit_bypass()) {
      // Bypass the session limitation on this page callback.
      return;
    }
    ..
```

**It clearly shows uid 1 is left intentionally.**

Answer (score 2):

While it's better not to allow UID 1 login for other admin users, instead creating separate administrator user accounts, if you *really* want to restrict UID 1 to a single session, it's possible.

You could basically copy `session_limit_init` to a custom module (with a dependency on the session_limit module), preserving the existing logic, and tweak it to apply only to UID 1. The UID 1 user will need one of the roles configured in the session limit module, e.g "administrator"

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 * 
 * This is a copy of session_limit_init
 * It extends the default session_limit functionality to apply to UID 1
 */
function MYMODULE_init() {
  global $user;
  // The only difference is $user->id == 1 instead of $user->uid > 1
  if ($user->uid == 1 && !isset($_SESSION['session_limit'])) {

    if (_session_limit_bypass()) {
      // Bypass the session limitation on this page callback.
      return;
    }

    $query = db_select('sessions', 's')
      // Use distict so that HTTP and HTTPS sessions
      // are considered a single session.
      ->distinct()
      ->fields('s', array('sid'))
      ->condition('s.uid', $user->uid);

    if (module_exists('masquerade') && variable_get('session_limit_masquerade_ignore', FALSE)) {
      $query->leftJoin('masquerade', 'm', 's.uid = m.uid_as AND s.sid = m.sid');
      $query->isNull('m.sid');
    }

    $active_sessions = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
    $max_sessions = session_limit_user_max_sessions();

    if (!empty($max_sessions) && $active_sessions > $max_sessions) {
      session_limit_invoke_session_limit(session_id(), 'collision');
    }
    else {
      // force checking this twice as there's a race condition around session creation.
      // see issue #1176412
      if (!isset($_SESSION['session_limit_checkonce'])) {
        $_SESSION['session_limit_checkonce'] = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        // mark session as verified to bypass this in future.
        $_SESSION['session_limit'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```